# Why is a Subject in RX called a "Subject"?

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming

Can anyone explain the reason behind the name? Observable and Observer is obvious, but I don't understand why it's called a Subject?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect the Rx team chose that name within a moment's thought because it is intended to play the same role as the Subject in [the original observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Although Subject implements both `IObservable<T>` and `IObserver<T>`, it is for its Observable qualities it is named.

It was the authors of the *original* pattern that chose it for the dictionary definition, because it is the subject that is being observed.

Comment: Confirmed by the man himself. https://twitter.com/headinthebox/status/401606868499316736

Comment: Good answer, and bonus points for getting it confirmed! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think the [dictionary definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subject) points in the right direction:  "the person or thing that is being discussed or described".

Remember, an [`ISubject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229572%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) is simply by definition an interface that is both observable and observer.  In that sense, a `Subject` instance is a sort of conversation hub, which other objects can send messages to, and/or or receive messages from.  But ISubject is also generic, so the messages in the conversation are restricted to objects of the generic type.  Both of those senses make an `ISubject` instance like "a thing that is being discussed".